# UTC time not getting converted to local for bootgrid?

Tags: jquery, datetime, time, datetime-format, jquery-bootgrid

i have a table to display the timestamp inside bootgrid. This timestamp is created using NOW() and is in UTC.I want to display this to local time while displaying inside bootgrid.The table head is as shown below.

```
<th data-column-id="ts" data-header-align="center" data-align="center" data-order="desc" data-converter="datetime">Upload Date</th>
```

I have written a converter for datetime to convert to local time using momnet

```
converters: {
        datetime: {
            from: function (value) { return moment(value); },
            to: function (value) { return moment(value).local().format("lll"); }
        }
    }
```

But the problem is that it is still displaying in UTC and not in local time.How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
var now = new Date(); 
var now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
```